# Xamarin Android create txt file that is editable by other app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android App where I want to create a txt file that is editable by another app

For now, I've successfully created the file with this code

```
string content = "this is content of the file";
string path = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "Documents");
File.WriteAllText(path, content);
```

But I can not edit that file with another App like TurboEditor or by Windows Notepad (if I connect my device to a windows machine). It seems like the file is set to readonly, and only my app can edit it.

TurboEditor throwing exception
`Permission Denial:Writing com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.providers.MyFilesFileProvider uri content://com.sec.android.app.myfiels.FileProvider/device_storage/Documents/file.txt from pid=895, uid-10219 requires the provider to be exported, or grantUriPermission()`

So how can I achieve this?

NB :

- I cannot edit the file, but I can delete it from android file explorer
- I create the file on `External Storage` in `Documents` folder
- TurboEditor is an app just like Notepad but on android, it's available on playstore

Comment: Please tell exactly why another app cannot edit your file. You really mean: cannot be edited by a program on my pc?

Comment: when I  try to edit it with TurboEditor it says "Permission Denial com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.providers.......... requires the provider be exported, or granUriPermission()"

Comment: How does TurboEditor know about your file? What did the user do? Or did your app invoke that editor? If so, then how? ACTION_VIEW? Then show your code.

Comment: `com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.providers` Is that your app?

Comment: The file is created by my app that I wrote, then I tried to edit that file with TurboEditor. TurboEditor is an app just like notepad but on Android, so I browse my file with TurboEditor, when I tried to save the file it says "Permission Denial .....".

Comment: no, `com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.providers` is not my app

Comment: So you say you can open and read the file with TurboEditor? Are you using an Android 10 device?

Comment: that's right, I can open and read the file, but cannot edit it. And yes i'm using Android 10

Comment: Use ACTION_VIEW and a FileProvider to serve your file to any app on the device that can handle that file.

Comment: ooh with that way you mean my app will serve the file and from user's perspective the user will choose the available app to open the file right ?? But what I expect is user manually opens TurboEditor, then browse the file created by my app. Maybe it looks stupid but that's just what my manager tells me to do xd

Comment: No nothing stupid. Quite normal wish. But if it does not work on Android 10... Pretty strange that the file can be openen though ans not saved. You should tell the developers of TurboEditor your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. So I already solve the issue, I don't know why this issue happens. I'll explain it in answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can edit the file. So with the code that I posted, you should be able to edit the file

I don't know why this happens, but here's how I found it

I can edit the file if

- Open TurboEditor
- Browse the file to edit
- Edit and save the file

BUT I cannot edit the file if

- Open My Files v 11.5.01.341 (Samsung file explorer)
- Browse the file that I want to edit
- Click on the file then popup "Open with" will show up and I choose TurboEditor
- Edit and save the file
- BOOM exception occurred

I'm using Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2019 Model SM-T515